# Connection 1-form on associated principal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Let $Q$ be a principal $H$-bundle for some (Lie) group $H$, and $\omega_Q\in \Omega^1(Q,\mathfrak{h})$ a connection 1-form on $Q$. Given an $H$-representation it is straightforward to construct a covariant derivative on the associated vector bundle.

I'm interested in the case where you have a group homomorphism $\alpha: H\to H'$ into some other group and want to construct a connection 1-form on the associated principal $H'$-bundle $Q\times_{\alpha}H'$ (where $H$ acts on $H'$ via left multiplication by $\alpha(H)$).

Is there some canonical way that $\omega_Q$ induces a connection form on this bundle? The only construction I could think of is the following:

Let $p:Q\times H\to H $ be projection onto the second factor, and $\omega'\in \Omega^1(H',\mathfrak{h'})$ the Maurer-Cartan form on $H'$. I have computed that the 1-form $\omega:= p^*\omega' \in \Omega^1(Q\times H', \mathfrak{h'})$ descends to a form on $Q\times_{\alpha}H'$ and satisfies the appropriate equivariance property $R_{h'}^*\omega= \text{Ad}_{(h')^{-1}}\omega  $ (and the verticality condition) and thus should be a connection 1-form on $Q\times_{\alpha} H'$.

**However**, $\omega$ doesn't "know" anything about the original connection $\omega_Q$ that we started with. Is there some way to put a connection on $Q\times_{\alpha}H'$ that is in some way constructed from $\omega_Q$?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't $\alpha$ induce a Lie algebra map $\mathfrak h\to\mathfrak h'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have computed that the 1-form $\omega:= p^*\omega' \in \Omega^1(Q\times H', \mathfrak{h'})$ descends to a form on $Q\times_{\alpha}H'$

I don't think this is true: firstly as Ted points out, the Lie group homomorphism $\alpha:H\to H'$ induces a Lie algebra homomorphism $\dot{\alpha} = T_e\alpha:\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{h}'$. For $(q,h')\in Q\times H'$ and $\xi\in\mathfrak{h}$, the vector along the quotient direction
$$
(q\cdot \xi, -\dot\alpha(\xi)\cdot h')\in T_{(q,h')}(Q\times H')
$$ 
when contracted with $\omega = p^*\omega'$ takes the value $-\dot\alpha(\xi)$, which is non-zero for $\xi\notin \ker \dot\alpha$. However this vector descends to the zero vector on $Q\times_\alpha H'$.

I haven't worked through the details, but I think the correct form to consider would be 
$$
\omega = \dot\alpha(p_1^*\omega_Q) + p_2^*\omega',
$$
where $p_1:Q\times H'\to Q$ and $p_2:Q\times H'\to H'$ denote the respective projections. It doesn't suffer from the above problem: applying it to the quotient direction $(q\cdot \xi, -\dot\alpha(\xi)\cdot h')$ yields 0, and so it should descend to a 1-form on $Q\times_\alpha H'$, which will be a connection.

**Edit:** I went back to work out the details of this, and it seems I was incorrect in my guess. The correct form should be
$$
\omega_{(q,h')} :=\mathrm{Ad}_{(h')^{-1}}\left(\dot{\alpha}(p_1^*\omega_Q )_{(q,h')}\right) + (p_2^*\omega_L')_{(q,h')}=\mathrm{Ad}_{(h')^{-1}}\left(\dot{\alpha}(p_1^*\omega_Q )_{(q,h')} + (p_2^*\omega_R')_{(q,h')}\right)
$$
Here $\omega_L' (\omega_R')$ is the left-(right-)invariant Maurer-Cartan form on $H'$. Letting $\pi_\alpha:Q\times H' \to Q\times_\alpha H'$ denote the quotient map,
$\omega$ vanishes on vectors of the form $(q\cdot\xi, -\dot\alpha(\xi)\cdot h')$ (i.e. vectors along the fibres of $\pi_\alpha$), and is invariant under the quotient action. So it reduces to a form $\omega_\alpha$ on $Q\times_\alpha H'$
$$
\omega = \pi_\alpha^*\omega_\alpha.
$$
The obvious right actions $R_\cdot$ and $\check{R}_\cdot$ of $H'$ on $Q\times H'$ and $Q\times_\alpha H'$ commute with $\pi_\alpha$,
$$
\pi_\alpha\circ R_{h'} = \check{R}_{h'}\circ \pi_\alpha,
$$
and it is straightforward to verify that $R_{k'}^*\omega = \mathrm{Ad}_{(k')^{-1}}\omega$ for all $k'\in H'$. It follows that
$$
R_{k'}^*\pi_\alpha^*\omega_\alpha = \mathrm{Ad}_{(k')^{-1}}\pi_\alpha^*\omega_\alpha \implies \pi_\alpha^*\check{R^*}_{k'}\omega_\alpha = \pi_\alpha^*(\mathrm{Ad}_{(k')^{-1}}\omega_\alpha).
$$
Since $\pi_\alpha$ is a submersion, this implies $\check{R^*}_{k'}\omega_\alpha = \mathrm{Ad}_{(k')^{-1}}\omega_\alpha$. Also $\omega_{(q,h)}((q,h)\cdot \xi) =\omega_{(q,h)}(0_q,h\cdot \xi) = \xi$ and the fact that $\pi_\alpha$ commutes with the right action implies the equivalent result for $\omega_\alpha$. So $\omega_\alpha$ is a connection form on $Q\times_\alpha H'$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! I will check the details and update my question.

Comment: I had in mind just applying $\dot\alpha$ to the original connection form. This certainly with representations and associated vector bundles.

Comment: @TedShifrin, do you mean just $\dot\alpha(p_1^*\omega_Q)\in\Omega^1(Q\times H',\mathfrak{h}')$? If so, this doesn't drop to the quotient $Q\times_\alpha H'$, for similar reasons to above. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was confused before about an extra adjoint factor that kept appearing, but this settles that problem.